# WPF Control Visibility w/ ICommand & OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a user window with 3 controls - an 'execute' button, a results control, and a processing control. My goal is to display the processing control after execute is pressed, then hide it when the execute method finishes.

However, the processing control does not display when I assumed it would... instead it only displays when (if) a callback function that creates another window prompting for user input is called.

The processing control has its visibility bound to a bool `Processing` in my viewmodel via BoolToVis converter. The execute method sets `Processing` to true at the start, then to false when it finishes. The setter of `Processing` calls `OnPropertyChanged.` My view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged.`

```
    private bool _processing;
    public bool Processing
    {
        get
        { return _processing; }
        set
        {
            _processing = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Processing");
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _search;
    public RelayCommand Search
    {
        get { return _search ?? (_search = new RelayCommand(p => OnSearch(), p => CanSearch())); }
    }
    private void OnSearch()
    {
        this.Processing = true;

        DoWork(delegate callBack);

        this.Processing = false;
    }
```

And some of the XAML:

```
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

    <me:ProcessingControl Visibility="{Binding Path=Processing, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Comment: You probably need to execute the `DoWork()` method in a background thread, either by using a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task<T>` from the TPL, or if you're using C# 5 (VS 2012) you can `await` on that.

Comment: I will try that. My curiosity remains, however. Shouldn't the control flow through OnPropertyChanged and update the UI before DoWork() is reached?

Comment: No, because you're keeping the UI Thread busy executing your DoWork() method and therefore it cannot refresh the UI until your code has completed executiion.

Comment: +1, this is exactly how I implement popups, except any and all synchronous time-consuming work should take place in a `BackgroundWorker`. Subscribe your work method to the `DoWork` event of the background worker and set `Processing = true`. Then subscribe a finishing method to `RunWorkerCompleted` in which you should set `Processing = false`.

Comment: @HighCore, I suggest you add your comments as an answer and have Michael accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Task or Background Worker to do DoWork, set Processing=true before starting the task or Background worker and make it false at the end of the task. This will enable Processing control to visible and hide. If your chaining the value of bool Processing in a task or back ground worker make sure you invoke it via dispatcher